# Contact Form 7: Call function only on submit of specific form

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I am coding my very first plugin. It is something like an addon for a theme, adding useful things to it.
One of these is, that I collect data of food and this is why I allow users to add different food via a contact form. The form itself is pretty standard, and I am using save_posted_data hook to  create the food post (as custom post type).

Looks like that:

```
function save_posted_data( $posted_data ) {

$form_id = $contact_form->id();
if( $form_id == 1903 ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'np-food',
        'post_status'=>'draft',
        'post_title'=>$posted_data['food-name'],
        'post_content'=>$posted_data['food-desc'],
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

    if(!is_wp_error($post_id)){
        if( isset($posted_data['food-name']) ){
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'food-name', $posted_data['food-name']);
        }
        // and so on
    }
}
return $posted_data;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'save_posted_data' );
```

My problem is: The part when checking the form, should only create a post when the chosen form is the one the user uses. But this does not work here, cause every other CF 7 form ends up in a infinite loop when clicking submit. Only the form 1903 does something (creates a post with desired meta fields). All other don´t work.

Does somebody know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the submission on `before_send_mail` and check for your field name to bail out.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_posted_data' );
function save_posted_data( $contact_form ) {

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $submission ) {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();    
    }
    // This checks for the form tag [food-name]
    if (empty($posted_data['food-name']) || !isset($posted_data['food-name'])) return;

    // Or use this to check for form by ID (remove previous if)
    // if ($posted_data['_wpcf7'] !== '{your_form_id}') return;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'np-food',
        'post_status'=>'draft',
        'post_title'=>$posted_data['food-name'],
        'post_content'=>$posted_data['food-desc'],
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

    if(!is_wp_error($post_id)){
        if( isset($posted_data['food-name']) ){
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'food-name', $posted_data['food-name']);
        }
        // and so on
    }
}
```

You can also use the field `_wpcf7` which contains the form ID `$posted_data['_wpcf7']`

So your "IF" would be this:

```
if ($posted_data['_wpcf7'] !== '1903') return;
```

For Multiple Form Submissions and functions you could do this:

```
if ($posted_data['_wpcf7'] == '{your_form_id}') {
    // do stuff when form id = first
} else if ($posted_data['_wpcf7'] == 'second_form_id') {
   // do more stuff
}
```

Comment: First of all: Thank you so much for helping out. I tried the first version and this seems to work. For my understanding... this is where you check the existing of a specific form field, right: if (empty($posted_data['food-name']) || !isset($posted_data['food-name'])) return; For the second version I am not sure how to build it. I just replaced the if line with yours and removed the bracket at the end, but the loop is still alive.

Comment: Should work if that is the form ID but if the first one works then roll with that

Comment: Thanks again. I just prefered the second version, cause it is easier to read for me. Now, both work :) Thanks so much. I searched for such an answer for days

Comment: There is one more question left :) Sorry. Is it possible to change the code to something like: WHEN FORM 1 is used, save post type MyCPT1, WHEN FORM 2 is used, save post type MyCPT2?... if I understand right, than "return" leaves the function. That means, that the same code for another form will not work, cause function was already left, right?

Comment: I've updated with some more... yes `return` exits the function.

Comment: you are awesome. Is this possible with the "check field version" too?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, you can make an if statement for any condition... whether you use form ID or fields present.  Just remember that when you use `wpcf7_before_send_mail` it's processing this before the mail sends (which the little ajax spinner is spinning) - so keep your processing short or it will slow the form.